# How to complete the square for this?

Tags: quadratics

How to express $2x^2 - 3x$ in the form $a(x+b)^2 + c$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants?

Comment: Set both expressions equal and compare coefficients.

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/complete-the-square-calculator

Comment: Can you please show me how? Because I did: 2x^2 -3x = ax^2 +2axb+ab^2+c.

Comment: then equate coefficients $2,-3,0$ with $a,2ab,ab^2+c$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a(x+b)^2 +c= ax^2+ 2abx + ab^2+c=2x^2 -3x$$
Comparing the coefficients,
$$a=2$$
$$2ab=-3$$
$$2(2)b=-3$$
$$b=\frac{-3}{4}$$
$$ab^2 +c=0$$
$$c=-ab^2=-(2)(\frac{-3}{4})^2= \frac{-9}{8}$$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of equating coefficients, you can also follow this straightforward procedure.

First factor out the leading coefficient, so that you can work with something of the form $x^2+bx+c$, and start completing the square by writing this as $\left(x+\frac{b}2\right)^2+d$ for some $d$ that remains to be determined:

$$\begin{align*}
2x^2-3x&=2\left(x^2-\frac32x\right)\\
&=2\left[\left(x-\frac34\right)^2+d\right]\,.
\end{align*}$$

Now

$$\left(x-\frac34\right)^2=x^2-\frac32x+\frac9{16}\,,$$

and what we want inside the square brackets is just $x^2-\frac32x$, so clearly $d$ must be $-\frac9{16}$ to get rid of the unwanted $\frac9{16}$ term:

$$\begin{align*}
2x^2-3x&=2\left[\left(x-\frac34\right)^2-\frac9{16}\right]\\
&=2\left(x-\frac34\right)^2-\frac98\,.
\end{align*}$$